# Strange shading issue

Tags: modeling, rendering, shaders

I am having a problem with these sections developing a dark line on an outside curve. It is consistent down the edge loop, and I was hoping someone had an idea of what is going on/ what I can do to fix it. It really only shows up in the rendering tab.
I have smooth shading on,
The bevel modifier is on the bottom edges (by weight) and not on the radius that is affected.
The texture is just a solid color.

[image: Screenshot of issue, edit mode]

[image: Screenshot, Object mode]

[image]

Comment: looks like it might be inverted normals.  Can you recalculate normals and see if it changes the problem?  (In edit mode, select all, and SHIFT-N)

Comment: I recalculated the normals a couple of times for good measure. It didn't change a thing.

Comment: can you add your blendfile to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: .blend file added. And thanks for having a look. I really appreciate it!

Comment: hello, could you please only keep the part where it happens, I can't find the artefact you're talking about

Comment: I think the reason others aren't finding the problem is that you might have hit an issue in Blender.  in 2.93.6, I'm seeing highlights where you're seeing a black band.  Which version of Blender are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you mean this, but maybe i am right.

So i think it is a z-fighting problem.

[image]

[image]

So if you uncheck Binding-Backup, the problem should be gone. Of course you should uncheck for both, viewport + render.

If this is not your problem, you should improve your question and show us exactly where your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, Chris. I unchecked the "extras" file and everything in it. That actually fixed another problem I was having but not this. Not really sure how to improve the question. If I understood it better I may not have the question at all;-) The dark line running through the object is not created by lighting or texture. The normals have been recalculated, anything occupying the same space has been made invisible, it should be solid off-white. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Couple years late, but I had a similar issue and after a few minutes looking for an answer I rotated around and realized I must have accidentally hit <kbd>F</kbd> while I had a loop selected so it filled in a face on the inside of the mesh causing this strange shading behavior in my model. Switched to face select mode and deleted the erroneous face and the shading on the outside of the mesh went back to normal!

Hope this helps anyone else looking for this problem/solution.